# Transpose column of values skipping blank cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Ztx.png

I need help, for example, I have a condition of thousands of data like in red border and want to form it like in result border

What kind of transpose formula do I have to use?
try to figure it out with this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A3:A&",",,55000))
```

but still don't find a suitable result

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(A3:A,,99^99), " "))
```

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A3:A, A3:A<>""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A3:A, A3:A))
```